# Clear Background color on UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hello i have a UIimageView with a PNG image that has round corners, image sits fine the only problem it has is that i can see the UIImage Corners with a white background, how can I make the background clear and transparent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imageView.opaque = NO;
```

You can achieve the same thing in IB by making the 'Background' a color with 0% opacity, and unticking the 'Opaque' checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```