# Creating UIIMageView from UIIMage results in an ImageView that has outer rectangle with gray fill

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656708/clear-background-color-on-uiimageview).  However, the answer in it is not working for me.  Hence, asking a new question with my code.

What I am trying to do.  I have an image of a paddle.  I am trying to create an imageView from this image.  Code I am using is below.  I am seeing the paddle image (which has rounded edges) is surrounded by a rectangle that has a grey fill.  (please see attached figure that shows the grey fill surrounding the ImageView).

I would appreciate any inputs on what I am doing wrong.

**My Code**

```
 self.paddleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle"]];
 self.paddleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 self.paddleView.opaque = NO;
 [self.paddleView setFrame:self.myModel.paddleRect];
 [self.view addSubview:self.paddleView];
```

**Code for paddleRect is**

```
UIImage* paddleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle.png"];
    CGSize paddleSize = [paddleImage size];
    self.paddleRect = CGRectMake(self.screenWidth/2, self.screenHeight-BOTTOM_OFFSET,
                                 paddleSize.width, paddleSize.height);
```

[image: Image showing the grey fill around imageViews]

Comment: Post an image of "paddle.png" itself.

Comment: I feel so dumb.. Yes, the image asset I got has the border!! I never opened just copied the file over and did not notice it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As matt pointed out, the issue was with the png I was using for my image views.